# Grouping bars in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to create a bar, where I would like to group revenue and production cost for each product. I get my data from a spreadsheet, and then handle them in matlab.

You can see what I've tried so far:

```
sP = cell2mat(Models(2:size(Models),4))
spy = cell2mat(Sales(2:size(Sales),2))

for i1 = 1:length(spy)
    car(i1) = spy(i1).* sP(i1);  
    sumSold = (car);
end

base = 13000

pCost = cell2mat(Models(2:size(Models),3))
production = cell2mat(Production(2:size(Production),2))
for i1 = 1:length(pCost)
    car(i1) = (base+pCost(i1)).* production(i1);  
    sumProductionCost = (car);
end

y = [sumSold; sumProductionCost]
```

My expected result from y, was something like this:

```
     1     2
     1     2
     1     2
     1     2
     etc..
```

Instead, I got this:

```
1.0e+10 *

0.3693    1.1881    3.2839    2.7604    1.6344    1.2941    2.4883    0.7949
0.3466    1.1025    3.0750    2.6163    1.5572    1.2001    2.3405    0.7481
```

And if I try to plot this in bars, I get 8 grouped bars distributed on two x axis point.

I want to achive the opposite; to have 2 grouped bars, distributed on 8 x axis point.

I'm new to this. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about your actual data because it's not clear what you intended with `sumSold = (car)`. But `sumSold` and `sumProductionCost` are both `1 x 8` so when you combined them to get `y`:

```
[sumSold; sumProductionCost];
```

The `;` concatenates them along the first dimension yielding a `2 x 8` array.

By default `bar` plots each *column* of the inputs as a group. You'll want to transpose the input so it is `8 x 2` and then you'll get two groups of 8 bars.

```
bar(y.')
```