# Grouped Bar graph Matlab

Tags: matlab, bar-chart

I'm trying to make a grouped plot bar in matlab, as the one you can see in this example:

[image: Grouped Plot Bar example]

Do you know how it could be made? This is all I made till now, and it doesn't work as I want.

```
y = [Cerrillos; Talagante];
bar(y)

title('Concentraciones 2015-2016')
xlabel('Estaciones')
ylabel('µg/m³')
```

Comment: y is numerical data with rows corresponding to groups and columns corresponding to individual columns, i.e. 12x2 matrix will give you 12 groups of 2 bars each. Please refer to bar help page in in-built help.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Grouping bars in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37527474/52738)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the grouped bar code:

```
y = [7 7; 21 15];
fig=figure();
a=bar(y)
XTickLabel={'Cerrillos' ; 'Talagante'};
XTick=[1 2]
set(gca, 'XTick',XTick);
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', XTickLabel);
set(gca, 'XTickLabelRotation', 45);
legend('2015','2016')

title('Concentraciones 2015-2016')
xlabel('Estaciones')
ylabel('µg/m³')
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfect!! Thanks a lot!!!!